# What software deploys NEX_SDK.dll?

Tags: winforms, windows-10-desktop

A site I am responsible for is reporting that when our Windows Desktop application (WinForms, .Net v4.7.2) displays a login or authorisation form, our application now reports an error:

```
The program can't start because nex_sdk.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Once this report is cleared, our program *continues* without issue.

Our software does not reference anything called nex_sdk and it is not on my development workstation either, and Google has never heard of "nex_sdk.dll" so I'm somewhat helpless here.

Imprivata single sign-on is in play so I'm hoping it's related to that and I can have local IT repair/reinstall but I'd need an authoritative statement that that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It is the Imprivata "Single sign-on" agent service/application.